# Bitbucket pipeline ignore git config

Tags: git, go, bitbucket

I am setting up a bitbucket pipeline for my go application and I have to go get a package from a private bitbucket repository.

I am trying to setup a gitconfig in my pipeline to use ssh instead of https

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.insteadOf https://bitbucket.org/
```

When I print my git config in the pipeline I can see that the value is correctly set, the problem is that when I do my go get my private repo, it seems to try to fetch via https instead of ssh.

Is there a way to force the pipeline to use the git config I set?

Comment: Where are you running this "git config" line?

Comment: I run it in step->scripts. The orders are; setup ssh private key, setup the git config, setup the goprivate (for bitbucket) and then last is to build my go application (fail to fetch my private package)

Comment: I've never used Bitbucket specifically, and each CI system is a bit different, but as a rule, pipeline operations are *run* in a private setup in which *nothing persists from one run to the next*. This means that `git config --global` is *erased*. To make some setting persist, use a *local* setting that runs every time the pipeline runs.

Comment: @torek this worked for me...pls post this as an answer.